# Text visibility change with button

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, visibility

I will be doing my new school project and I want to know, how can I change text visibility with button? Like when I click the button, text will be visible and when I click it again, it will be invisible or when I click another button it will be invisible. Either with JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: You should attempt to do something and ask for a solution if you are stuck.

Comment: Problem is, I don't even know how to start. I can't find how to change text visibility with button. I could only find for image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<html>

<body>
    <p id="hiddenText">this text is visible now</p>
    <button onclick="show()">Show</button>
    <button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
</body>
<script>
    function show(){
        document.getElementById("hiddenText").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hide(){
        document.getElementById("hiddenText").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is not like "gib mi solushons" type of website.
Try writing some code and sharing it here. Here is a resource to study from: https://www.w3schools.com/
Look at JS `onclick` event.
CSS `display`
and HTML tag syntax structure.
It might help you.
Then try to post again when you have some code to show and we will gladly help you.

Comment: Thank you and sorry about that, I am absolutely new to this website.